# Calling Javascript from WCF Web Service

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, wcf

Is this even possible? Some post mentioned Signal R??

The only examples I have came across was calling Jscript from the code behind of an ASPX file using  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript ???

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using SignalR, [SignalR Hubs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server) to be precise. Basically, it uses persistent web socket connection to communicate between clients and server. Thus, you can execute methods on server side (Hub) from JavaScript (you can pass parameters and get returned value) and vice versa.